# Optimizing a SQL Query when joining two tables. Naive algorithm gives me millions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I apologize, I am not sure how to word the heading for this question. If someone can reform it for me to better suit what I am asking that would be greatly appreciated.

I have a quite a problem that I have been stuck on for the longest of time. I use Tableau in conjunction with SQLServer 2014.

I have a single table that essentially shows all the employees within our company. Their hire date and termination date (NULL if still employed). I am looking to generate a headcount forthe past. Here is an example of this table:

```
employeeID    HireDate    TermDate    FavouriteFish    FavouriteColor
    1           1/1/15     1/1/18         Cod               Blue
    2           4/12/16     NULL          Bass              Red
    .
    .
    .
    n
```

As you can see this list can go on and on.. In fact the table in question I currently have over 10000 rows for all past and current employees.

My goal is to construct a view to see on each day of the year for the last 5 years what the total head count of employed employees we had. Here is the kicker though... I need to retain the rest of the information such as:

```
FavouriteFish    FavouriteColor... and so on
```

The only way I can think of doing this,and it doesn't work so well because it is extremely slow, is to create a separate calendar table for each day of the year for the past 5 years; like so:

```
Date       CrossJoinKey
1/1/2013        1
1/2/2013        1
1/3/2013        1
    .
    .
    .
4/4/2018        1
```

From here I add a column to my original Employee Table called: CrossJoinKey; like so..

```
employeeID    HireDate    TermDate    FavouriteFish    FavouriteColor    CrossJoinKey
    1           1/1/15     1/1/18         Cod               Blue            1
    2           4/12/16     NULL          Bass              Red             1
    .
    .
    .
    n
```

From here I create a `LEFT JOIN Calendar ON Employee.CrossKeyJoin=Calendar.CrossKeyJoin`

Hopefully here you can immediately see the problem.. It creates a relationship with A LOT OF ROWS!! In fact it gives me somewhere around 18million rows. It gives me the information I am after, however it takes a LONG time to query, and when I import this to Tableau to create an extract it takes a LONG time to do that as well.. However, once Tableau eventually creates the extract it is relatively fast. I can use the inner guts to isolate and creating a headcount by day for the past 5 years... by seeing if the `date` field is in between the `termDate` and `HireDate`. But this entire process needs to be quite frequently, and I feel the current method is unpractical.

I feel this is a naive way to accomplish what I am after, and I feel this problem has to have addressed before in the past. Is there anyone here that could please shed some light on how to optimize this?

Word of note... I have considered essentially creating a query that populates a calendar table by looking through the employee table and 'counting' each employee that is still employed, but this method loses resolution and I am not able to retain any of the other data for the employees.

Something like this, shown below, works and is much faster, but NOT what I am looking for:

```
Date       HeadCount
1/1/2013        1200
1/2/2013        1201
1/3/2013        1200
    .
    .
    .
4/4/2018        5000
```

Thank you very much for spending some time on this.

UPDATE:
Here is a link to a [google sheets data sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1knAjmH5zYQIq9AFcYlbpIH3QheKF7lQ1dMurwXH-tjY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Firstly: you don't want to cross join. You want to join on `calendar date between HireDate and ISNULL(TermDate,'2099-01-01')`. (I just reread your question and saw that you tried this) However... even if this reduced your report to say.. 100,000 rows... who can make sense of 100,000 rows? What is the purpose of the report?

Comment: One thing that isn't clear is whether you need the Emp ID vals or not ...
If not - Then you can create "Dimensions" for favoritecolor etc and have 1 record per day per dimension and a Numeric Headcount Measure for # of employees. (You can even "Junk" multiple dimensions together to reduce rows)

Comment: You need a tally table for this. And you shouldn't get 100,000 rows. You would get a single row for each date. Can you provide some sample data? Like a little more than 2 employees. A dozen or two. Then I can show you how to use a tally table to build this very easily.

Comment: @ Nick.McDermaid This report is to show our executive the headcount over the past 5 years using our WorkDay database that houses all employee information

@SeanLange I will edit the original post with a link to a google sheets sample data... Give me a moment thank you.

@ johnMcTighe Would you be able to provide an example?? That sounds like the way to go

Comment: Instead of posting a link to a spreadsheet can you post this in a consumable format? http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Here is where I am confused. "Here is the kicker though... I need to retain the rest of the information such as". What does that mean? Are you saying in your view you want aggregate data AND details? That doesn't make sense. How can you expect summary and aggregate data?

Comment: Your sample data is useless. You have a number of people that were termed before they were hired. If the data was viable what do you expect as output?

Comment: @SeanLange the reason I need to retain the rest of the data is for example, in tableau I can create filters and paramters that allow me to see headcount based on various criteria. For example: let's look at the headcount as a whole, but now let's look at it looking at all employees are 30 years old... or lets see headcount for the last five years filtering out employees with no college education... etc

Comment: @SeanLange sorry let me clean it up.. i used a random function to quickly generate some dates.. EDIT: should be cleaned up now.

Comment: I don't know anything about tableau but you can't have it both ways. The way you would query for that sort of thing would be to use a where clause.

Comment: If you just construct one query or view with the head counts per day (no other details) and then use the original table for fetching any of the details you need to see -- just fetch those records where the date in question is between start and termination. It's still a little bit unclear how you actually need to see the favourite fish when it comes to different days.

Comment: Are you certain you need it for _every_ day? every headcount report I've seen has been end of month. Who cares what the difference is between Tuesday and Wednesday?

Comment: To speed it up you could preload once into a table (adding to it as time goes on) and read from the table. Or you could index your source table properly. There are many solutions for this

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. It has made me consider how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited some of your data, as you can see in the @example table.

I wanted to note: you either spelt =D favourite or Color incorrectly, Please correct it, either FavoriteColor, or FavouriteColour.

```
declare @example as table (
    exampleid int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   StartDate date not null
,   TermDate  date null
);

insert into @example (StartDate, TermDate)
select '1/1/2016',  '1/1/2018' union all
select '4/3/2017',  '1/10/2018' union all
select '9/3/2016',  '2/4/2018' union all
select '5/9/2017',  '11/21/2017' union all
select '9/18/2016', '11/15/2017' union all
select '12/12/2015', '2/8/2018' union all
select '6/18/2016', '12/20/2017' union all
select '7/26/2015', '11/4/2017' union all
select '1/7/2015',  NULL union all
select '10/2/2013', '10/21/2013' union all
select '10/14/2013',    '12/12/2017' union all
select '10/11/2013',    '11/3/2017' union all
select '6/30/2015', '1/12/2018' union all
select '2/17/2016', NULL union all
select '8/12/2015', '11/26/2017' union all
select '12/2/2015', '11/15/2017' union all
select '3/30/2016', '11/30/2017' union all
select '6/18/2016', '11/9/2017' union all
select '4/3/2017',  '2/12/2018' union all
select '3/26/2017', '1/15/2018' union all
select '1/27/2017', NULL union all
select '7/29/2016', '1/10/2018';

  --| This is an adaption of Aaron Bertrand's work (time dim table)
  --| this will control the start date

  declare @date datetime = '2013-10-01';

   ;with cte as (
             select 1 ID
               , @date date_
           union all

          select ID + 1
               , dateadd(day, 1, date_)
            from cte
                  )
            , cte2 as (
          select top 1000 ID
               , cast(date_ as date) date_
               , 0 Running
               , iif(datepart(weekday, date_) in(1,7), 0,1) isWeekday
               , datepart(weekday, date_) DayOfWeek
               , datename(weekday, date_)  DayOfWeekName
               , month(date_) Month
               , datename(month, date_) MonthName
               , datepart(quarter, date_) Quarter
            from cte 
          --option (maxrecursion 1000)
                    )
        , cte3 as (
        select a.id 
             , Date_
             , b.StartDate
             , iif(b.StartDate is not null, 1, 0) Add_
             , iif(c.TermDate is not null, -1, 0) Remove_
          from cte2 a
          left join @example b
            on a.date_ = b.StartDate
          left join @example c
            on a.date_ = c.TermDate
         -- option (maxrecursion 1000)
                    )

        select date_
             --, Add_
             --, Remove_
             , sum((add_ + remove_)) over (order by date_ rows unbounded preceding) CurrentCount
             from cte3
            option (maxrecursion 1000)
```

> Result Set:

```
date_       CurrentCount
2013-10-01  0
2013-10-02  1
2013-10-03  1
2013-10-04  1
2013-10-05  1
```

Comment: @Arron Bertrand - Thanks; and here is his blog with his original works: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/